# How to fix : http://URL: not authorized error in eclipse while cloning project from GIT?

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm cloning a project from GIT using URL, I'm getting this error after insert my username and password : **http://URL : not authorized**,

**how can I fix this error ?**

This is a project in Eclipse using GIT, I already tried to clone the project and it was a positive result, but after change my session password, I face this problem and I can not clone the project.

You find here the log error : 
!SESSION 2019-01-18 15:55:26.493 -----------------------------------------------

```
eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
java.version=1.8.0_201
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 2 0 2019-01-18 15:55:34.083
!MESSAGE Builtin LFS support not present/detected
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.BuiltinLFS cannot be found by org.eclipse.egit.core_5.0.0.201806131550-r
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator.registerBuiltinLFS(Activator.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator.start(Activator.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator$RepositoryChangeScanner.<init>(Activator.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator.setupRepoChangeScanner(Activator.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator.start(Activator.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchServiceRegistry.getSourceProviders(WorkbenchServiceRegistry.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.SourceProviderService.readRegistry(SourceProviderService.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$34.runWithException(Workbench.java:2378)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading.runWithoutExceptions(StartupThreading.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.initializeDefaultServices(Workbench.java:2373)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1654)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2859)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1498)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2019-01-18 15:55:43.957
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\noureddine.ergaibi'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide 2 17 2019-01-18 15:55:44.702
!MESSAGE Server ‘org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide.server’ failed with exception: Proxy Error. ; version: 2.0.7.v20170906-1327
!STACK 0
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Proxy Error
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseStringHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses$ProgressMonitorResponseStringHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponses.java:1)
    at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Response.handleResponse(Response.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.HttpResponses.getContentWithProgress(HttpResponses.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.IO.refreshConfiguration(IO.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ide.server.mars.ServerConnection.startUp(ServerConnection.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$DelegateService$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:62)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$4.run(Callables.java:122)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 4 0 2019-01-18 15:56:49.549
!MESSAGE Could not acquire INavigatorContentService: Project Explorer not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 4 0 2019-01-18 15:58:26.811
!MESSAGE http://pvntp768-ptfs2:8080/tfs/Finance/_git/E-Invoice%20Dashboards: not authorized
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: http://pvntp768-ptfs2:8080/tfs/Finance/_git/E-Invoice%20Dashboards: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: http://pvntp768-ptfs2:8080/tfs/Finance/_git/E-Invoice%20Dashboards: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:200)
    ... 4 more
!SESSION 2019-01-18 16:02:48.962 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.8.0.I20180611-0500
java.version=1.8.0_201
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 2 0 2019-01-18 16:02:55.471
!MESSAGE Builtin LFS support not present/detected
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.lfs.BuiltinLFS cannot be found by org.eclipse.egit.core_5.0.0.201806131550-r
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator.registerBuiltinLFS(Activator.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.Activator.start(Activator.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator$RepositoryChangeScanner.<init>(Activator.java:921)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator.setupRepoChangeScanner(Activator.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.Activator.start(Activator.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:931)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchServiceRegistry.getSourceProviders(WorkbenchServiceRegistry.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.SourceProviderService.readRegistry(SourceProviderService.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$34.runWithException(Workbench.java:2378)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
.......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is unrelated. Git does not clone via unencrypted `http:` with credentials. Use a `https:` or `ssh:` URL.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols